# How to add and send data with POST method two actions?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm working on symfony 1.4, I have an indexSucces file where I show a form, this form has text boxes where you enter data and has a combo with two options. if the user selects option 1 and click the button data is sent to the accion 1, and if the user selects option 2 data are sent to accion 2. But apart from data provided by the user, other data must be sent. 
This is the code of the indexSuccess

```
 <form method="post">
<?php echo $form['textfield']->render();  ?>
<?php echo $form['combo_options']->render();?>
 <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar"/>
</form>
```

This is the code of actions.class.php

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request){

$this->form=new FormularioForm();

 if($request->isMethod('post')){

 if($request->getPostParameter('enviar')){

  $data=$request->getParameter('textfield');

  $option=$request->getParameter('combo_options');

if($option=='1'){

$data_extra=array(1,2,3,4,5);

//How with the post method to send the $data and $data_extra to the next action1?

$this->redirect(aplication/action1);

}else{

$data_extra=array(8,9,7,5);

//the same here

$this->redirect(aplication/action2);
}}}

public function executeAction1(sfWebRequest $request){
//Here I receive the data sent with $ request-> getParameter ()
}
```

Comment: Please remove the symfony2 tag.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to store the extra data in the user session, as example:

```
// Store data in the user session
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('extra_data', $extra_data);

$this->redirect(...);
}}}

public function executeAction1(sfWebRequest $request){

// Retrieve data from the user session with a default value
$extra_data = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('extra_data', array('no elem'));

}
```

More info [here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_accessing_the_user_session)

Hope this help